# [Bootstrap][Tables] Transition on hover for .table-hover Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

do you have an idea of how to use the CSS transition for `tr` when the table has a class `.table-hover` in BS 5? When I add for example `transition: 0.5s` to the code below it doesn't work?

```
.table-hover {
  > tbody > tr:hover {
    --bs-table-accent-bg: var(--bs-table-hover-bg);
    color: var(--bs-table-hover-color);
  }
}
```

I think this is caused by adding background-image to the cell here:

```
  > :not(caption) > * > * {
    padding: $table-cell-padding-y $table-cell-padding-x;
    background-color: var(--bs-table-bg);
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--bs-table-accent-bg), var(--bs-table-accent-bg));
    border-bottom-width: $table-border-width;
  }
```

Thank you for your help!
Best,
Marta

Comment: Try add transition on `.table-hover {
  > tbody > tr` add initial value on it and add your target transition value on `.table-hover {
  > tbody > tr:hover`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for Bootstrap 5 tables.

Comment: it's works, because i'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  --bg: whitesmoke;
  --color: black;
}
table tbody tr {
    background: var(--bg);
    color: var(--color);
    transition: 0.5s
}
table tbody tr:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```